# initCoreNLP() method call from the Stanford's R coreNLP package throws error

Tags: r, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use the `coreNLP` package. I ran the following commands and encounter the *GC overhead limit exceeded* error.

```
library(rJava)

downloadCoreNLP()

initCoreNLP()
```

Error is like this :

> Loading classifier from   edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Error in rJava::.jnew("edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", basename(path)) : 
>     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>   Error during wrapup: cannot open the connection

I don't know much of Java, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@indi I ran into the same problem (see [R's coreNLP::initCoreNLP() throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983149/rs-corenlpinitcorenlp-throws-java-lang-outofmemoryerror/35010559)) but was able to come up with a more repeatable solution than simply rebooting.

The full syntax for the init command is

```
initCoreNLP(libLoc, parameterFile, mem = "4g", annotators)
```

Increasing `mem` did not help me, but I realized that you and I were both getting stuck with one of the classifiers in the `ner` annotator (named entity recognition). Since all I needed was parts-of-speech tagging, I replaced the init command with the following:

```
initCoreNLP(mem = "8g", annotators = c("tokenize", "ssplit", "pos"))
```

This caused the init command to execute in a flash and with no memory problems. BTW, I increased `mem` to 8g just because I have that much RAM. I'm sure I could have left it at the default 4g and it would have been fine.

I don't know if you need the `ner` annotator. If not, then explicitly list the `annotators` argument. Here is a list of the possible values: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/annotators.html. Just pick the ones you absolutely need to get your job done. If you do need `ner`, then again figure out the minimal set of annotators you need and specify those.

So there you (and hopefully others) go!

Answer (score 2):

I found a more general solution: increase the heap space for rJava, as described [here](https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/solution-using-r-the-following-error-is-returned-javalangoutofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded):

*Cause*: The default heap size for libraries that rely on rJava is 512MB. It is relatively easy to exceed this maximum size.

*Solution*: Increase the JVM heap size in rJava's options support:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4096m")
```

Note that **this step must be performed prior to loading any packages**.

---

Then I ran:

```
initCoreNLP(mem = "4g")
```

...and the entire CoreNLP loaded and ran successfully.

Comment: Hadn't realised that setting java.parameters step must be performed prior to loading any packages! it finally works! Gold help.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following, but in vain -

options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")     - to increase the heap size
gc() - which will cause a garbage collection to take place automatically

Ultimately got solved on its own after restarting my machine!