# R's coreNLP::initCoreNLP() throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: r, stanford-nlp, rjava

`coreNLP` is an R package for interfacing with Standford's CoreNLP Java libraries. The first line one must execute (after loading the appropriate packages with the `library()` command) is `initCoreNLP()`. Unfortunately, this results in the following error:

> Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Error in rJava::.jnew("edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP", basename(path)) : 
>     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Note, this is the same problem that is listed here: ([initCoreNLP() method call from the Stanford's R coreNLP package throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015823/initcorenlp-method-call-from-the-stanfords-r-corenlp-package-throws-error)). In that case, however, the OP found that rebooting his machine made the problem disappear. This is *not* the case for me; I keep experiencing it even after a reboot.

Has anyone else run into this and can provide a solution or suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
DG

## CONFIG DETAILS:

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

rJava version 0.9-7

coreNLP version 0.4-1

Machine: Win 7 with 8GB RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some documentation I found:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coreNLP/coreNLP.pdf

(specifically page 7)

You can specify how much memory you use (from the documentation):

```
initCoreNLP(libLoc, parameterFile, mem = "4g", annotators)
```

Add more memory and I would imagine the problem will go away.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've actually already tried that and it does not solve the problem. I've used mem = 6g, 8g, 12g, 16g, and 32g (note my machine only has 8g of RAM so I don't know why it would even try to run with arguments larger than that).

Comment: Whoops. Hit <return> too soon...  :)   Anyhow, if you guys are the official help for Stanford NLP and your suggestion didn't work, I guess I'm really screwed. Maybe I'll see if I can call the Stanford Java libraries from R without using the coreNLP package. Thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: You might look into the Stanford CoreNLP server.  If you start up a Stanford CoreNLP server you can then make POST requests and get results.  I have no idea how to do that in R but I would think R would have some tools for that.  Here is the link: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

Comment: Also are you sure you're giving R enough memory?  It looks like the Java process is getting an appropriate amount of memory but maybe R is having the problem.

Comment: This link has some info on R's RAM limits: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html

Comment: Thanks again for your replies. While changing the memory didn't solve the problem, your reminding me of the syntax of initCoreNLP did! I realized that it was running out of memory while trying to load one of the packages (referenced above) that is part of the `ner` annotator (named entity recognition). Since all I really need CoreNLP for in this case we parts-of-speech analysis. So I explicitly listed the `annotators` argument for `initCoreNLP` and had plenty of memory for the annotators I actually needed.

So thanks for all your help. I couldnt' have done it without you!

Comment: @DojoGojira i was hoping to use your method to solve my problem which seems to be exactly as yours. Unfortunately the initCoreNLP() no longer provides the annotator option in the new CoreNLP package!